# google talk / libjingle developer forum

Tags: google-talk, libjingle

Does anyone know if there is a libjingle developer forum?

The link provided at  https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/index under "Support" throws a "You do not have permission to access this group. (#418)" error.

Other places I could find are http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/issues/list, but that is only for bugs. And the activity at Stackoverflow seems low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mailed one of the google developers and he told me that libjingle does not have a specific forum. He suggested we try the WebRTC mailing list instead

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/discuss-webrtc

Since libjingle is effectively a subset of WebRTC, and WebRTC has a more active community.

Although if you have an issue, you can add the issue to:

http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/issues/list

Comment: Frustrating that they don't say thin on their website. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

I was going to ask the same question, and this question has been open for 2 months, which makes me think the answer is no. Also, I'll add that the link to google talk help center on the [google talk blog](http://googletalk.blogspot.com/) goes to archive.org! I searched for other google groups that cover libjingle and they are filled with spam.

Moreover, the current compilation instructions for Mac OS X require a lot of work (I documented this here: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/09/compiling-libjingle-on-os-x.html). So I'm guessing this means google is quietly reducing their level of support for libjingle.

I think the best place to get support is right here.